# Esri-Leaflet getFeature returns 'undefined'

Tags: leaflet, feature-layer, feature-service, esri-leaflet

I'm using Esri-Leaflet and whenever I try to use `getFeature()` the `console.log` returns "undefined".

There are no other errors to accompany the undefined message.

```
var service = L.esri.featureLayer({url: 'https://services1.arcgis.com/example/arcgis/rest/services/LayerName/FeatureServer/0'});
var objID = parseInt("4");
var featurePoly = service.getFeature(objID);
console.log(service.featurePoly);
```

A feature of ObjectID of 4 does exist. The feature service is reachable.

Any thoughts on where I might be going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this seems to be that:

The featureService must have been added to the map. `.addTo('map');`
The map must be set to viewing coordinates that causes the features to be returned to the map.

It's not possible to work with features that have not been added to the map, apparently.